How can I fix sudo apt update missing public key?
I am trying to run sudo apt update on my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4 and I get the following:
Get:1 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Release
Ign:2 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Release
Get:3 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Packages
Ign:3 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Packages
Get:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Ign:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Get:3 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Packages
Ign:3 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Packages
Get:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Ign:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Get:3 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Packages
Ign:3 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Packages
Get:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Ign:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Get:3 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Packages
Ign:3 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Packages
Get:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Ign:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Get:3 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Packages
Ign:3 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Packages
Get:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Ign:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Get:3 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Packages
Ign:3 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Packages
Get:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Ign:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Get:3 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Packages
Get:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Ign:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Hit:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports InRelease
Hit:6 https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public InRelease
Hit:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bullseye InRelease
Hit:8 https://openmediavault.github.io/packages shaitan InRelease
Get:9 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports InRelease [49.0 kB]
Get:10 https://openmediavault-plugin-developers.github.io/packages/debian shaitan InRelease [3934 B]
Hit:11 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Hit:12 http://packages.openmediavault.org/public shaitan InRelease
Err:9 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY 6ED0E7B82643E131
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://httpredir.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY 6ED0E7B82643E131
E: The repository 'http://httpredir.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

I have tried adding the keys (0E98404D386FA1D9 & 6ED0E7B82643E131) and have also followed this fix but it still didn't work for me and I'm not sure what to do now. I definitely don't want to allow an insecure connection.
Sources.list.d (folder) and sources.list (file) respectively:
bullseye-backports.list  openmediavault-kernel-backports.list  plexmediaserver.list            vscode.list
omvdocker.list           openmediavault-local.list             plexmediaserver.list.dpkg-dist
omvextras.list           openmediavault.list                   raspi.list

# See sources.list(5) manpage for more information
# Remember that CD-ROMs, DVDs and such are managed through the apt-cdrom tool.
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org bullseye-security main contrib non-free

# Uncomment if you want the apt-get source function to work
#deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://security.debian.org bullseye-security main contrib non-free

Here's information on my OS (if that helps):
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)" 
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux" 
VERSION_ID="11" 
VERSION="11 (bullseye)" V
ERSION_CODENAME=bullseye 
ID=raspbian ID_LIKE=debian 
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/" 
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums" BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"

